# PySpark convert empty string to null and write in Parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to convert empty strings to Null (None) and then write out in Parquet format.

However, the output is still an empty string and not Null (None). Any ideas what I need to change? I am using `Spark 2.4` and `Python 3`

**Note:** I am checking columns for String Data Type before applying the below, but I have omitted for simplicity of this question.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

for column in df.columns:
    df_new = df.withColumn(
        column,
        psf.when(
            psf.length(
                psf.trim(
                    psf.col(column)
                )
            ) != 0,
            psf.trim(psf.col(column))).otherwise(None))
```

Comment: your code is not only trying to replace empty strings `""` with nulls since you are trimming them. Now assuming you are writing `df_new` to a parquet file, your code will only replace the last column with nulls since you are doing `df_new = df...` in your loop. Also you can use `df.replace("", None)` to replace everything by nulls, although you would have to trim columns first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you’re assigning the return value of the transformations to `df_new`, and Spark transformations create a *new* DataFrame (DataFrames are immutable structures), you’re basically only changing the last (string) column.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame((("a", "b"), ("", "b"), ("a", "")), schema=("A", "B"))

for column in df.columns:
    trimmed = psf.trim(psf.col(column))
    df_new = df.withColumn(
        column,
        psf.when(psf.length(trimmed) != 0, trimmed)
        .otherwise(None))
df_new.show()
# +---+----+
# |  A|   B|
# +---+----+
# |  a|   b|
# |   |   b|
# |  a|null|
# +---+----+
```

However, if you change the line `df_new = df.withColumn(` by `df = df.withColumn(`, you’ll get the desired result:

```
for column in df.columns:
    trimmed = psf.trim(psf.col(column))
    df = df.withColumn(
        column,
        psf.when(psf.length(trimmed) != 0, trimmed)
        .otherwise(None))

df.show()
# +----+----+
# |   A|   B|
# +----+----+
# |   a|   b|
# |null|   b|
# |   a|null|
# +----+----+
```